# jQuery - remove background-color when an element is visible

Tags: jquery, background-color, visible

I would like to remove the background-color (only the background-color) of the menu once another element is visible. I wrote this code, but it doesn't work - anybody can help?

```
$(function() {
if($("#wrapperHome").is(":visible")) {
    $("#menu a").css({ "background-color", "black" });  
}
});
```

The menu has this background style sheet information.

```
background:url(img/official/menu.png) center center no-repeat #f2f2f7;
```

Comment: `$("#menu a").css({ "background-color" : "transparent" });`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I believe you want something like this...

```
$("#menu a").css("background-color", "");
```

Setting the background-color to "" essentially removes the styling, removing the color.

Answer (score 3):

Use `:` not `,` when doing key/val CSS changes:

```
$("#menu a").css({ "background-color" : "black" });
```

Or since it's one value:

```
$("#menu a").css("background-color", "black");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move the style into the css for your site. This avoids having css littered through out your js and you can then re-use it.

```
.selected-menu-item{ // or what ever it is that has a black background
  background-color: black;
}
```

Then in your jquery:

```
$("#menu a").toggleClass("selected-menu-item");
```